# How to complete missing values by group, using value in the same variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
 variable value         un2       n  prop     desired-result-for-un2
   <chr>    <fct>         <fct> <int> <dbl>         <fct>
 1 CHR_01   Never         0         2   1             0
 2 CHR_01   Almost Never  NA        0   0             0
 3 CHR_01   Sometimes     NA        0   0             0  
 4 CHR_01   Often         NA        0   0             0
 5 CHR_01   Almost Always NA        0   0             0
 6 CHR_011  Never         1         1   0.5           1
 7 CHR_011  Almost Never  1         1   0.5           1
 8 CHR_011  Sometimes     NA        0   0             1
 9 CHR_011  Often         NA        0   0             1
10 CHR_011  Almost Always NA        0   0             1
11 CHR_02   Never         0         1   0.5           0
12 CHR_02   Almost Never  0         1   0.5           0
```

In the first line, the `un2` variable has a 0 value. I would like to complete the un2 variable by the `variable` groups using the available value in each group.
That is lines from 2 to 5 (first group) complete with 0s, complete NAs with 1s in all missing value for that group, etc... such as in the `desired-result-for-un2` column.

Any dplr trick to make it would be welcome,
Thanks in advance,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

We could use `fill` after grouping by 'variable'.  The NAs will be filled by the last non-NA in the downward direction first and then the upward (`.direction`)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    fill(un2, .direction = 'downup') %>%
    ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @akrun for this answer.
I found one answer by:

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    mutate( un4 = rep( unique( na.omit(un2)  , n()  ) ))
```

However I do not find it very clean...

Comment: use `unique(na.omit(..))` No need to repeat since mutate will do that for you